# How can I display Firebase Firestore data in order?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have my Firestore structure as follows:

```
entries > {entryUIDs} > pnum
```

where entries is the collection and entryUIDs are all the documents.

I want to display all of my data in the entries collection in order of the pnum, which starts at 1 and every document has a number increased by one.

I want to be able to display it on a simple html site where each document is ordered by the pnum field.

For now I'm testing this simply using:

```js
store.collection('entries').get().then(snapshot => {
  setupSite(snapshot.docs);
});

const setupSite = (data) => {
  let html = ``;
  data.forEach(doc => {
    const entry = doc.data();
    const list = `<a href="${entry.path}">${entry.title}</a>`;
    html += list;
  });
  document.body.innerHTML += html
}
```

Any help on how to order these documents would really help, as at the moment they are displayed by their Firestore Document UID.

Comment: Have you tried following the [documentation on ordering queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data)?  I suggest making an attempt, and if that doesn't work the way you expect, then post your code along with your debugging details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using orderBy while querying

```
store.collection('entries').orderBy("pnum", "asce").get().then(snapshot => {
setupSite(snapshot.docs);
});
```

Comment: 'asce' doesn't seem recognized, my script simply stops showing. [edit: if i order by pnum without the asce tag will that order ascending by default?]

Comment: Yes, by default it is in ascending but if you want descending you have to pass "desc" in orderBy